# $1$-norm of the inverse of lower Toeplitz-like triangular matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-norms, toeplitz-matrices

In recent days, I need to estimate the 1-norm (or $\infty$-norm) of the inverse of the following lower Toeplitz-like triangular matrix, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
C = \begin{bmatrix}
1  &\\
-2 &\frac{3}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}&-2 &\frac{3}{2} \\
&\ddots & \ddots &\ddots\\
& &\frac{1}{2}&-2&\frac{3}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}.
\end{equation}
After I use the MATLAB to compute the inverse of the above matrix with different size $N$, it seems that we have

1. $\|C^{-1}\|_1\leq \frac{3N}{2}$;
2. $\|C^{-1}\|_{\infty} = N$.

where $\|C\|_1 = \max\limits_{1\leq j\leq N}\sum\limits^{N}_{i=1}|C_{ij}|$ and $\|C\|_{\infty} = \max\limits_{1\leq i\leq N}\sum\limits^{N}_{j=1}|C_{ij}|$.

Can we prove these conclusions?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I will add the definition of the matrix norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following two closed form formulas:
$$
\|C^{-1}\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(3^i-1)/2}{3^{i-1}},
$$
and
$$
\|C^{-1}\|_\infty=\frac{(3^N-1)/2}{3^{N-1}}+\sum_{i=2}^N \frac{3^{N-i+1}-1}{3^{N-i+1}}.
$$

Comment: many thanks for your answer, I got it according your reminder.